# Joining list with different separators in Python

Tags: python, list, join, formatting

I am a novice and can't figure out how to solve this. I have a list that I am iterating over to print multiple lines. I've got it so that a new line is started after every 5th element. My issue is that I can't figure out how to format the result with multiple separators. Right now I've got dashes separating. Here's my code:

```
source_list = [all, of, my, data...]
for print_list in zip(*[iter(source_list)] * 5):
    print(' - '.join(print_list))
```

This output:

```
blahblah - blah - blahblahblah - blahblah - blah
blah - blahblahblah - blahblah - blahblah - blahblahblah
```

That's close. But I need the formatting to look like:

```
blahblah (blah) - blahblahblah - blahblah - blah
blah (blahblahblah) - blahblah - blahblah - blahblahblah
```

The needed output is a set pattern of ( ) - - -. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: May we please see the real input / output data?

Answer (score 0):

```
items = ['all', 'of', 'my', 'data', … ]

for i in range(0, len(items), 5): 
    print('{} ({}) - {} - {} - {}'.format(*items[i:i+5]))
```

This works only for `len(items)` a multiple of 5.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I was trying to do.